# How come a single reputation user able to comment and ordering of comments that are converted from answers to comments?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, comments

In a [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/114799/27149) I asked few days back a user named [ajay](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/116446/ajay)(with 1 reputation point) answered my question which was flagged for deletion by me and then user [Izzy added a comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/114799/moto-g2-speaker-phone-issue-when-calling/115037#comment143145_114799) on behalf of ajay and flagged his answer for deletion. Since it was more like a comment rather than an answer, the solution provided by ajay was deleted yesterday. But the exact answer is seen now as [a comment from ajay under my question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/114799/moto-g2-speaker-phone-issue-when-calling/115037#comment143207_114799).

Considering a user has to get to gain 50 reputation points to get the commenting previlege. How is this possible for a user with one reputation to comment? Does the user allowed to comment or Is it something that a moderator has an option/tool that has converted the answer to a comment. Because it is shown as commented 4 days back but I haven't seen the comment yesterday. I have no idea how can this happen so, Can some explain this to me?

And how these comments that are converted from answer to a comment ordered? Is this added as the last comment to the question or does it have some ordering based on timestamp?

**Update:**

In my case that ajay has answered(11th July) before user @Izzy commented(14th July). So that I thought ajay's comment is visible before Izzy's comment based on timestamp. I'm confused on how the ordering of comment is based on and does diamond mods have special priorities on the comment section?

Comment: Just as confirmation: I don't remember having seen ajay's comment when I "converted his answer" either, so the 2nd strange thing is how it comes to appear before mine. Makes me look stupid somehow :)

Comment: No it was not there when you comment until I just saw the comment today from ajay after his answer was deleted.

Comment: Thanks for that feedback, Lucky! I was already questioning my sanity #D

Comment: @Izzy Based on [this comment from eldarerathis♦](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/1975/answered-bounty-in-comment-not-answer#comment4466_1975) mod stating _"Moderators can move answers into comments"_ I get that Moderators(♦) can turn answers to comments and the reason in the order it is appearing before your comment is based on timestamp of the answer(My guess totally). ;).

Comment: Yupp, that was my guess too. Good find!

Comment: Correct, the answer was converted to a comment by @matthewread

Comment: Also, I cleaned up your comments on that question since they are no longer needed :)

Comment: I didn't realize Izzy had commented when I did this, apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the answer was converted to a comment by @MatthewRead

Comment: What is the order of the comments that are converted from "answer to comments" displayed? See my updated question.

Comment: @Lucky it uses the same timestamp as the original answer, see this image for example: http://i.imgur.com/Kt3DIxT.png

Comment: Yes it uses the same timestamp..But my question is When that answer is converted to a comment, where does this comment actually go? Is it displayed as a last comment or some sort of ordering based on timestamp? Both are conflicting with my question and Firelords case. It is not displayed as a last comment and in Firelord's case it is not displayed in order of timestamp.

Comment: Comments are ordered by timestamp, so it would be inserted into the list of comments at the appropriate timestamp of the conversation. So in this case, the comment was inserted before Izzy's.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't answer that because I'm not a mod there and cannot see the full history of that question and its answers. I would assume the answer was added after the mod's comment, then converted to a comment, which would correctly put it after the mod's comment. But that's just my assumption.

Answer (score 1):

While Bryan Denny ♦ already cleared the mist [here](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1977/96277), I strictly recommend reading the question: [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75189/286110), and the very  helpful answers there including [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75192/286110) which says:

> Diamond moderators are human exception handlers. The main function of diamond moderators is to follow up on flagged posts but they also have some special abilities necessary to handle rare exceptional conditions:
>
> - They have access to all the abilities of 20k users regardless of their reputation.
> - Their votes are binding. Any place we have voting — close, open, delete, undelete, offensive, migration, etc — that vote will reach the threshold and take effect immediately if a single diamond moderator casts a vote.
> - They can lock posts. Locked posts cannot be voted on, commented, or changed in any way.
> - They can see more data in the system, including vote statistics (but not ‘who voted for this post’) and user profile information.
> - They can view all deleted posts on an individual user's profile.
> - They can place users in timed suspension, and delete users if necessary.
> - They can perform large-scale maintenance actions such as merging questions and tags, tag synonym approvals, unbounded question migration, and so forth.
> - They can convert a post into Community Wiki status, **or convert an answer into a comment**.
> - They can (at their discretion) refund and cancel a bounty.
> - They are not subject to the flag, close vote, delete vote, review count, etc. limits. ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189303/180276))

<sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>

E.g. [This comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/22610/identification-of-the-background-music-played-in-episode-2-and-3-of-beyblade-sea#comment33023_22610) on my question was initially posted as an answer by an unregistered user (having 1 reputation point), but was later added as a comment by a Mod.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer but one more thing Izzy asked on comments that how did ajay's comment went before his comment. I guessed it was aligned with the order of timestamp. But the comment you mentioned in your answer in not reflecting that. I'm still confused with how the ordering of comments took place. Is there any priorities for visiblity or something to diamond mods in comments section?

Comment: @Lucky Good point. I suggest you edit the question and reflect this confusion about ordering of comments and time stamp a bit more, because it was possibly missed by Bryan while answering, and I missed it somehow too. In the mean time I'll see if there is any related post somewhere on other meta sites.